# mvc one to many relation lec.id not found

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am writing the one to many relation code in asp .net mvc but it is giving the following error

The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'mvcpractice.Models.EmpLect'. A member of the type, 'lec_id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Following is the code i am already declared the lec_id.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace mvcpractice.Models
{
    [Table("lecEmp")] 
    public class EmpLect 
    {
       [Key]
        public int lec_id { get; set; }

        public int empid { get; set; }
        public string lectures { get; set; }

        public virtual EmployeeTable empT { get; set; }

    }
}
```